# Extend default AccountController/Manage with custom UserProfile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

The default MVC 4 application includes an AccountController which does implement the usual account related methods. After you're logged in, you have  `Account/Manage/` which uses `LocalPasswordModel` to enable you to change your password and manage your external login if OAuth is activated.

After extending the UserProfile with additional data I would like to give my user an option to change it. I could create a new View that uses the `UserProfile` as model, but I would like to add it to the existing Manage view, but that one is using `LocalPasswordModel` as a model.

I apologize if my question is really basic, but how can I combine the two?